# Why System.getenv("HOMEPATH") return not absolute path on Windows?

Tags: java

On Linux `System.getenv("HOME")` return absolute path `/home/user`, but on Windows return `Users\user`.

Comment: For me it returns `\Users\myUser`, which is an absolute path to the main drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `System.getProperty("user.home")` if you want something that works the same on multiple operating systems.

`System.getenv` is operating-system or context dependent - there is no guarantee whatsoever that `System.getenv("HOME")` returns anything in particular on a given operating system, it's just luck that what you get on Unix is anything similar to what you get on Windows.

From the Javadoc for `System.getenv`:

> An environment variable is a **system-dependent** external named value.

For `System.getProperty`, there is a list of properties that you can get in a system-independent way:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()

One of them is `user.home`: "User's home directory"

Answer (score 3):

On Windows the home drive is specified separately in `HOMEDRIVE` variable. Concatenating it with `HOMEPATH` gives you the absolute path:

```
String home = System.getenv("HOMEDRIVE")+System.getenv("HOMEPATH");
```